# Loading multiple files in Qt for WebAssembly

Tags: c++, qt, file-upload, webassembly, qfiledialog

I need to use a file dialog in order to upload several files from client to server. I am aware about `QFileDialog::getOpenFileContent()`, but what about multiple files uploading (multiselect using file dialog in some directory) in Qt for WebAssembly? I don't mind against workaround.

I have tried

```
void QFileDialog::getOpenFileContent(const QString &nameFilter, const std::function<void (const QString &, const QByteArray &)> &fileOpenCompleted)
```

the signature says that I've got only one pair <name, content>. But I'd like to have multiple files selected and loaded using single dialog execution.

Comment: I think you need to explain what issue you had when you tried.

Comment: @drescherjm, `void QFileDialog::getOpenFileContent(const QString &nameFilter, const std::function<void (const QString &, const QByteArray &)> &fileOpenCompleted)` signature says that I've got only one pair <name, content>. But I'd like to have multiple files selected and loaded using single dialog execution.

Answer (score 2):

If you need multiple file support, use the HTML input tag, then you need to feed the files to the Qt app by using emscripten bindings, you can export a function to javascript, that way you can call it once the user has selected the files

```
<input type="file" id="files" multiple>
```

The details are quite complicated, but this is just an idea.